# iSCSI paths are alternately active and dead after connecting second ESX server

Tags: iscsi, vmware-esx

Multiple Virtual Machines (VMs) reside on an ESX server (**ESX1**) and are stored on iSCSI.

Connecting a second (**ESX2**) to iSCSI seems to work fine as a VM is created and stored on iSCSI. However inactive systems on ESX1 have been changed from e.g. system.test to *system.test (inaccessible)*.

At a certain moment *system.test (inaccessible)* suddenly changed to system.test again on **ESX1** and everything seems to work fine again. However, the inactive systems on **ESX2** were changed to *system.test (inaccessible)*.

It appears that the iSCSI paths are alternately active and dead. If the paths are active on **ESX1** then they are dead on **ESX2** and vice versa.

*Configuration tab > iSCSI adapter > Paths:*

[image]

vs.

[image]

The iSCSI adapter on **ESX2** has been identically configured as the one residing on **ESX1**. It is possible to create a VM on **ESX2** and store it on iSCSI. However, at a certain moment the iSCSI paths are dead and the inactive VMs become inaccessible while the running ones keep running. The question is how this issue could be solved.

Comment: What type of storage device are you connecting to?

Comment: @ewwhite [TGTD](http://stgt.sourceforge.net/manpages/tgtd.8.html) is used. I am searching the right command to allow multiple connections. Perhaps `-C` could be used, but I have not tested it yet and do not know whether it will work or not.

Comment: Hmm. I dunno. I wish more people would use NFS for VMware ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the iscsi target on the storage device you need to specifically allow multiple simultaneous connections otherwise each time one link connects it will disconnect the other (as a precautionary measure).

Also, you are creating a cluster of some sort?  You realise multiple VMs can't both access the same disk simultaneously under normal circumstances? This is not like network sharing.

Comment: [TGTD](http://stgt.sourceforge.net/manpages/tgtd.8.html) is used. I am searching the right command to allow multiple connections. Perhaps `-C` could be used, but I have not tested it yet and do not know whether it will work or not.